# Rending dynamic erb.html template files globally in RubyonRails 5 application

Tags: ruby, templates, import, ruby-on-rails-5, render

There are some elements I use globally in different sections such as sidebar-user. So I wanted to create a separate template file for this and import into pages when I need.

So, I created a folder **views/applications** and created **_sidebox-user.erb.html** file in it.

[image]

and I used the code below to render in index.erb.html

```
      <!-- SIGN UP/LOGIN BOX -->
      <%= render 'sidebox-user.erb.html' %>
```

But it renders as seen below instead of running my ruby codes in the template file ‍♂️

[image]

What am I missing here?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The actual rendering is done by subclasses of
>   ActionView::TemplateHandlers. The file extension on your view controls
>   the choice of template handler. Beginning with Rails 2, the standard
>   extensions are .erb for ERB (HTML with embedded Ruby), and .builder
>   for Builder (XML generator).

The extension is `name_of_file.html.erb`, note ERB must be specified as the "final" extension, as your file is named `_sidebox-user.erb.html` then is being used just as a html file.

Rename it to `_sidebox-user.html.erb` and it should work. Note you can use just the name, the extension is infered:

```
<%= render 'sidebox-user' %>
```